# Customize confirmation popup in Lightning application

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

After hitting submit I have a confirmation popup. I'm able to customize it's message, but it also adds in the sandbox/user name to the top of the message. Is there a way to get rid of that?

Here's the popup I have :

[image]

The code in my Helper.js for it:

confirm('Application submitted, thank you ' + newForm.First_Name__c);

Comment: Unless you make your own modal, no. The domain name is added to help prevent iframe spammers from pretending to be another page ("You've been logged out, click [here}<malware link here> to log back in"). Modifying it is probably not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by battery.cord, this is an intentional security feature, and cannot be circumvented. If you want to show a friendlier message, consider using the [lightning:overlayLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_overlayLibrary.htm), which can show Lightning dialogs.